# Field where $e^2 + f^2 = -1$ implies existance of matrix $A$ with $A^2 = -E_2$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, noncommutative-algebra

Suppose we have a field $K$ with a solution for $e^2 + f^2 = -1$. Is there a matrix $A \in K^{2\times 2}$ with $$ A^2 = \begin{pmatrix}-1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix}? $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try first with a symmetric matrix, because $-E_2$ is symmetric. Consider the equation
$$
\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ b & c \end{bmatrix}^2=
\begin{bmatrix} -1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{bmatrix}
$$
that becomes
\begin{cases}
a^2+b^2=-1 \\[4px]
ab+bc=0 \\[4px]
b^2+c^2=-1
\end{cases}
The second equation yields $c=-a$ or $b=0$; discarding the latter case which would imply $a^2=-1$, which we know nothing about, we get
$$
a^2+b^2=-1
$$
Thus choosing $a=e$, $b=f$ and $c=-e$ we are done.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
e & f \\
f & -e
\end{array}
\right)
$$